# Mockito throw exception when object argument value matches pattern

Tags: java, mockito

Seems simple but I can not come up with valid structure.

I want to throw an exception whenever `Path` to the file contains certain regex. I have a list of files that I loop and whenever I come across invalid `Path` exception is thrown and file is not added to the list of successful files.

Trying to test it with Mockito like:

```
    doThrow(DefaultException.class).when(service).foo(any(Path.class), any(Path.class));
```

where obviously I am missing the part where the excpetion would be thrown is for example the path has some certain regex in it as for now it is throwing exception for every file.

Is there a way to replace `any(Path.class)` with something that would meet my needs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
    Matchers.argThat(new ArgumentMatcher<Path>() {
        @Override
        public boolean matches(Object o) {
            Path p = (Path) o;
            if(p.toString().equals("some")) {
                return true;
            }else {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
```

instead of `any(Path.class)`.

PS: `p.toString().equals("some")` is sample condition. Replace it with real one.

Comment: Or simply `Matchers.argThat(p -> p.toString().equals("some"))`.